# how to create insert function in model

Tags: php, codeigniter

In controller I am sending data like that :

```
$data=array[
    'table'=>'ci',
    'where'=>'',
    'val'=>['name'=>$name,
        'pass'=>$pass,
        'mobile'=>$mobile,
        'date'=>$date,
        'status'=>$status
    ]
];
$this->load->model('show_model');
$this->show_model->insert_data($data);
```

In the model code I have:

```
<?php
class show_model extends CI_model{

    public function insert_data($data){
    }
}    
?>
```

I want to create a function to data in ci table what is the method to get the data from the controller and how can i make the funcyion for insert for what i am sending the data.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking a question about a bug, or wanting us to implement your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: For example, you have a syntax error here:

`array[`

It should be `array()`, or in PHP7, `[]`, but not `array[]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to perform insert operation but you couldn't figure it out. Lets take it step by step. Codeigniter has a database library which comes with installation. You can load that library in config->autoload.php and provide database credentials in config->database.php. All set!

Once you have loaded database library you can use bunch of database function. E.g

For Insertion

```
 $this->db->insert('table_name',data);
 // Your data can be array of the data you want to insert
```

Let's say you want to send data from your controller to your Model to save it to db you can do something like this

```
 Class Controller_Name extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('your_model');
      }

      public function index() {
          $data=array(
                      'username' => 'Your Name',
                      'email'    => 'Your Email',
                      'password' => 'Your Password'
                );
          // Send it to DB
          $this->your_model->save_data($data);
          // Show success
          echo 'Data Saved';
      }
 }
```

Now in your Model you will have the function save data like this

```
 Class Your_model extends CI_Model {
      public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
      }

      public function save_data($data){
          // Assuming the table name is users
          $this->db->insert('users',$data);
      }
 }
```

You can do a lot of modifications and enhancements, there is a lot of learning ahead but this is a fair start.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function insert($data) {

    if($this->db->insert('table_name', $data)) {

         //Success

    }
}
```

Ensure you are connected to your database from database.php in application/config folder

Hope it helps